# importing csv with pandas and drop strings in the data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following csv structure:

```
(
(0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)
some string might be in here
(0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)
)
```

I would like to import this with pandas but I need help with separating the data.

Currently I have:

```
data = pd.read_csv("myFolder/myFile", header = None, skiprows=22, engine ="python")
```

However it imports the data in a single column. I would like to remove the parenthesis and the strings in the data.

For the parenthesis, I have:

```
data =data.replace(to_replace='\(', value=" ", regex=True)

data =data.replace(to_replace='\)', value=" ", regex=True)
```

However, I do not know how to split the data by columns and how to drop the strings.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain further how the CSV is structured? It doesn't appear there are any commas in these comma separated values.

Comment: They are separated by spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module to search for relevant lines:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

r = re.compile(r"^\s*\((.*)\)\s*$")

data = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        m = r.search(line)
        if m:
            data.append(m.group(1).split())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           0          1     2
0  0.0078125  0.0078125  0.05
1    0.03125  0.0078125  0.05
2     0.0625  0.0078125  0.05
3  0.0078125  0.0078125  0.05
4    0.03125  0.0078125  0.05
5     0.0625  0.0078125  0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a series like so:

```
>>> s = pd.Series('''(0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
(0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)'''.split('\n'))
>>> s
0    (0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
1      (0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
2       (0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)
3    (0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)
4      (0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)
5       (0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)
```

You can just extract all numbers matching this numerical pattern (which requires a leading `0` for decimals) and unstack them to columns:

```
>>> s.str.extractall(r'(\d+\.\d+)').unstack()
               0                 
match          0          1     2
0      0.0078125  0.0078125  0.05
1        0.03125  0.0078125  0.05
2         0.0625  0.0078125  0.05
3      0.0078125  0.0078125  0.05
4        0.03125  0.0078125  0.05
5         0.0625  0.0078125  0.05
```

If you want a flat multi-index to the lower level, just reassign columns as `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the csv into 1 pandas column, then use regex to filter and clean all rows at once, then split the raw into columns:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'raw':['(0.0078125 0.0078125 0.05)', '(0.03125 0.0078125 0.05)', '(0.0625 0.0078125 0.05)', 'some string might be in here']})

data['raw'] = data['raw'].str.replace('[()]', '', regex=True)
# drop rows that have anything other than period, space, or digit
data = data[~(data['raw'].str.contains('[^. 0-9]', regex=True))]

data_split_up = data['raw'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

print(data_split_up)
#            0          1     2
# 0  0.0078125  0.0078125  0.05
# 1    0.03125  0.0078125  0.05
# 2     0.0625  0.0078125  0.05
```